# Android Development: Connect to single Google account

Tags: android, google-app-engine, oauth-2.0, android-developer-api

There is a way to connect to a user specific account stored on the phone. I do not want that. I want to connect to a predefined account that may not exist on the phone. How would I go about specifying what account to to connect to explicitly in the code more specifically in the code snippet:

```
 mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(Drive.API)
                .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();
    }
```

I do not quite understand where the connections occurs here...

Please ask questions if I am not clear.

Comment: This answer may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19766912/how-do-i-authorise-a-background-web-app-without-user-intervention-canonical

Comment: Also see the GoogleApiClient.Builder documentation here: https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient.Builder.html

Comment: I am brand new developer. I get the idea but I do not understand what do do with the information generated. Your suggestion is pretty much spot on though! @PaulSasik Isnt Plus outdated nowadays?